# Laravel 5.6 Error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, routes

i am trying to edit default Auth user in laravel and i get the error when i submit my edit form
so here is my controller :

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()

{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function edit(User $user)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('admin.profile.edit', compact('user'));
}

public function update(User $user)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
    ]);

    $user->name = request('name');
    $user->email = request('email');
    $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));

    $user->save();

    return back();
}
}
```

and here is my view file when of form i just put the form here

```
    <form method="post" action="{{route('users.edit', $user)}}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('patch') }}
                    <input type="text" name="name"  value="{{ $user->name }}" />

                    <input type="email" name="email"  value="{{ $user->email }}" />

                    <input type="password" name="password" />

                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" />

                    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
```

so the important file which i 90% sure that the problem is with is my route i know that i am some how sending some get to post or vise i am really confused with this part

```
Route::get('admin/profile/{user}',  ['as' => 'users.edit', 'uses' => 'UserController@edit']);
Route::post('admin/profile/{user}/update',  ['as' => 'users.update', 'uses' => 'UserController@update']);
```

so now when i submit the form i get this error

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

and btw i have tried to use patch route with hidden input too but yet again same out put .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok  So found the problem i have to change the user edit route to user update so

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('users.edit', $user)}}">
```

would be changed to this

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('users.update', $user)}}">
```